# How to set the SQS redrive allow policy in Java CDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-cdk, dlq

I'm using Java CDK to create a queue and a dead-letter-queue (DLQ) in AWS.

In my DLQ, I need to set the `Redrive allow policy` to enabled so that it can be used as DLQ, but I can't find the function in CDK that allows me to set it.

```
        Queue queueDlq = Queue.Builder.create(this, "queue-dlq")
                .build();
        Queue queue = Queue.Builder.create(this, "queue")
                .deadLetterQueue(DeadLetterQueue.builder()
                        .queue(queueDlq)
                        .maxReceiveCount(5)
                        .build())
                .build();
```

When I deploy this code, both queues are created. The main queue has the Dead-letter queue set correctly, but the DLQ doesn't have Redrive allow policy enabled to allow it to receive the messages.

Comment: there's an example here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/java/index.html?software/amazon/awscdk/services/sqs/DeadLetterQueue.html - but it looks pretty like your code. Are you sure you actually receive messages unsuccessfully in "queue"?

Comment: You need to use:
DeadLetterQueue deadLetterQueue = DeadLetterQueue.builder()
The deadletterqueue is a different kind of sqs and not the same as the default sqs queue